# sorting in bash and replacing characters

Tags: bash

i miss ideas. How to convert a file
whose content is as below:

```
./2018/09/28/RMDB_CDA
./2018/07/31/RMDB_CDA
./2018/06/29/RMDB_CDA
./2020/02/28/RMDB_CDA_NEW
./2020/01/31/RMDB_CDA_NEW
```

to return the two latest unique rows,
output:

```
2018-09-28:RMDB_CDA
2020-02-28:RMDB_CDA_NEW
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: What do you know about `sort` and `tail` — and `sed`?  What constitutes 'latest unique rows'?  For each distinct bit of verbiage after the date, the most recent date, and then just the last two lines of the complete list of distinct bits of verbiage?

Comment: Your question is also very unclear. Could you write down the specifications of your questions in a bit more detail. Example: **(1)** do you want to have the last two entries in the file (example output shows first entries) in file **(2)** what do you mean with "the two latest"

Comment: Also, show us what you've tried so far. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sort as desired and pick the first entry by `awk` for the corresponding field.

```
$ sort -r file | awk -F'/' '!a[$NF]++'

./2020/02/28/RMDB_CDA_NEW
./2018/09/28/RMDB_CDA
```

adding formatting and final sorting order

```
$ sort -r file | awk -F'/' -v OFS='-' '!a[$NF]++{print $2,$3,$4 ":" $NF}' |
  sort

2018-09-28:RMDB_CDA
2020-02-28:RMDB_CDA_NEW
```